# Customize system emails

Tags: emails

Is there a way customizing the emails that Joomla send automatically? For example emails with username e passwords sent to new users registered by some administrator.

In particular I need to insert some HTML code in them. I found the way of changing the text via language overrides but if I insert some HTML there the emails do not arrive any more.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is, it's a total pain. Most of the emails are in the language files, so you have to hack html into those and pray it works. The better way to do it IS with a plugin, and there are several options:

1. Acyba as mentioned by Max [Acyba site](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/362-acymailing-joomlanotification.html)
2. Email Beautifier by TechJoomla (though it may contain backlinks) [Techjoomla site](https://techjoomla.com/products/email-beautifier)
3. CMandril by Compojoom (this one requires a Mandrill account) [Compojoom site](https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/mandrill-transactional-emails-made-easy)

Comment: I agree with Brian, some of the emails are easy to edit and some are broken up in parts that are not consistent in their location, esp around the new user emails.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what are your needs, but language overrides can help with most of the problems. On this way you can add HTML code into the language override and that means you can include most of the things you want.
Changing CORE files sometimes could be difficult and on next Joomla update that will be overridden again (in most cases).

Try with language override. If you are using Joomla 3 you can go to Extensions > Languages > Overrides > New.
Then on new window search for the "Value" - your existing text, and then just update that text to what you want. You can add more text than you have today.

Comment: This post is more to keep default Joomla setup without installing additional components/plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Acy Mail component with plugin joomla override e-mails.

https://www.acyba.com

I hope this helps.

Comment: and what about doing it without any plugin?

Comment: Hi, Red. Sorry, but i dont have this skills. I use this component free version and customize emails sent by joomla. Works fine for me. Sorry.